# MathProg out of domain

Tags: glpk, mathprog

I need to solve a problem using GLPK and what Actually I need is to calculate the difference between elements in two arrays 
but, I receive error out of domain 
I hope that you can fix it as I've no idea about this error
here's the  code

```
set cols1;
set cols2;
set w;
set range:=1..2;
#set Groups;
#set Items{Groups} ;
param p1{cols1}>=0;
param p2{cols2}>=0;
param uf{w}>=0;
var x>=0;
maximize regret: x;
s.t. a: sum { i in range } (p1[i] -p2[i]) * uf[i]>=x;
s.t. b: sum { i in range } p2[i] * uf[i] =1;
data;
set cols1:=40  110;
set cols2:=51 134;
set w:= 0.8 0.2;
#set Groups := {cols1, cols2, w};
end;
```

Comment: What is the error? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint `b` doesn't contain variables, only parameters:

```
s.t. b: sum { i in range } p2[i] * uf[i] =1;
```

Perhaps this is causing the out of domain error in glpk. It is better to rewrite it as a check statement:

```
check: sum { i in range } p2[i] * uf[i] =1;
```

Also there is no data for parameters `p1`, `p2` and `uf`.

Answer (score 0):

The Out of Domain Error is located in your `sum{i in range}` statement of your two constraints.

Parameter `p1{cols1}` is indexed as following

```
p1[40]
p1[110]
```

in your sum statement you index p1 with `range` which is neither `40` nor `110`.

There are a couple of other things on this gmpl example. A Correct indexing would look like:

```
set range:={1,2};
param p1{range}>=0;
param p2{range}>=0;
param uf{range}>=0;
var x>=0;
maximize regret: x;
s.t. a: sum { i in range } (p1[i] -p2[i]) * uf[i]>=x;
s.t. b: sum { i in range } p2[i] * uf[i] =1;
data;
param p1:=1 40 2 110;
param p2:=1 51 2 134;
param uf:= 1 0.8 2 0.2;
end;
```

But then there is still the less technical Issue with Problem. Like vitaut already mentioned your secound constraint don't look right and will turn your Problem still infeasible. Because your parameters won't satisfy the `equal 1` constraint.

```
51 * 0.8 + 134 * 0.2 != 1
```